# How to share ResourceDictionaries in composite WPF Application?

Tags: wpf, inversion-of-control, unity-container, prism, resourcedictionary

Have build composite WPF App with Unity Ioc (without Prism).
All my resources (Styles, Templates, Pics) stored in one module (Infrastructure) and merged in Shell-module's App.xaml.

In other modules I use it as StaticResource. Everything works fine when I start the project, but in VisualStudio Designer I can't see my Styles: 'the resource *xyz* could not be resolved'.

How should I configure VS to see all resources also in designtime?

Possible Solutions:

1. I could merge everything in each module, but then each resource would be loaded multiple. I could also write my own ResourceDictionary implementation (like: [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html)), but I used to merge resources anyway everywhere - I would avoid this.
2. I have found a Prism reference solution for a composite application. I don't know how, but there it works without custom ResourceDictionary and without merging it in each module. VS Designer shows everything, although XAML Editor still says "the resource *xyz* could not be resolved"
   Question: is it a feature of Prism? Or there is some configuration hidden?

Comment: Do you have a link to the reference application?

Comment: @AndrewHanlon you mean prism reference? You cyn find it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx

Comment: Have found alternative solution, similar to 1.)
https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/WPF-Design-Time-Support-(Part-2)

But I still need to add such workaround to each module. As I wrote - Prism solution doesn't need anything as I can see in solution explorer. Is it really prism feature? Can't test it cause I use .net 4 and newest prism needs .net4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple (has nothing with Prism to do).

All resources should be defined in Shell module (not in Infrastructure module).
Then all modules should be referenced in Shell module project.

No need to merge resources in each module.
Each module knows only high level modules, and only shell knows everyone.

Comment: I doubt that the shell should reference any modules, that defeats the purpose of a module, somehow. And you can declare resources in modules (that the shell knows nothing about at compile time), and merge them on module initialization like this: `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri( "pack://application:,,,/MyModule;Component/Resources/SomeDatatemplates.xaml" ) } );`

Comment: @Haukinger what about main style? Duplicate it in each module?
Where should I then register my modules (if not in shell)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's practical for styles, but code used by all modules goes into an assembly referenced by all modules. As for module catalog - you can go for a configuration file (if the customer needs to make changes) or you can load all files as modules that match a certain pattern (like `*.module.dll`) with a catalog implementation like this https://prismextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SmartDirectoryModuleCatalog

Comment: @Haukinger sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I don't speak about code for all modules, rather about styles and resources (like pics, templates). 

My modules don't know anything about shell, and shell knows all modules, cause theese will be registered and loaded in shell code. I don't need to make it configurable for user.

Comment: if your shell references all the modules, why use modules in the first place? you cannot swap them out without recompilation then, so there's no real benefit. [wir können das auch per Mail besprechen, wenn Du willst, stackoverflow at haukinger punkt de]